# Can a W1209 be run with 5 V DC only?

Tags: sensor, heat, thermostat

I would like to control a small heat pad using a W1209, using a power bank that provides 5 V. My circuit is working if I connect the step-up voltage controller to the power bank and increase its voltage output to 12 V, so that the W1209 can be powered as required, but it makes a large current flow through my pad.

If I can run at 5 V, the current can be small. Can I bypass the 12 V voltage regulator and replace the relay with a 5 V relay? I didn't find any relevant example or blog post on this. The below is the closest I found, but not much use:

[Can I take DC directly from W1209 Thermostat board?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/371071/can-i-take-dc-directly-from-w1209-thermostat-board)

[image: proported schematic]

Comment: I found the schematic at https://tenbaht.github.io/sduino/hardware/w1209-thermostat/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it would work from 5 V if you remove and bridge over the voltage regulator IC2 to let the 5 V through and replace the relay with a 5 V part.

It may also be necessary to reduce the resistance of R7 to increase the current to Q1 because the 5 V relay coil will use more current than the 12 V one  so a stronger base drive may be needed.

[image]

Comment: Relay to control 12V with 5V.if heating pad 5V, relay not needed. Could be just MOSFFET. Relay coil consume to much.

Comment: yeah, a logic mosfet could work there too. take gate drive from pin 10 of the microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and explanation. May I use  MOSFET STP36NF06L. I have this at hand now.

Comment: the data sheet says that MOSFET will work with 5V \$V_{GS}\$ , so yes. should be good up-to about 5A, more with a heatsink.

Comment: Thank you so much. Instead of removing the voltage regulator, can I just short the input and output?

Comment: If you leave the regulator in circuit, it will consume at least its quiescent current of 5-10mA, which is a waste, though it is a small percentage compared to the heater.